# How to isolate string from multiple files put them in one output file with file name as header in UNIX

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I have some directory with multiple files with the extention .failed
This files have the following format:

**file1.failed:**

```
FHEAD|4525|20170109000000|20170125024831
THEAD|150001021|20170109121206||
TDETL|4000785067||1|EA|||RETURN|||N
TTAIL|1
THEAD|150001022|20170109012801||
TDETL|4000804525||1|EA|||RETURN|||N
TTAIL|1
FTAIL|6
```

I need to extract all the text between THEAD| and |2 to a output file.
im trying the following and it works only if i have only one file in the directory.

```
sed -n 's:.*THEAD|\(.*\)|2.*:\1:p' <*.failed >transactions.log
```

**The output is:**

**transactions.log:**

```
150001021
150001022
```

Now how can i do the same but for multiple files?
Also it is possible to add the filename in the output file?

**expected output:**

```
file1.failed
150001021
150001022
file2.failed
150001023
150001024
150001025
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -sn '1F;s/^THEAD|\([^|]*\)|.*/\1/p' file1 file2 file3 ...
```

Use the options `-n` and `-s` to invoke the grep-like nature and treat each files addresses separately. Display the current file name on the first line of the file only. Substitute and print the value between the required strings.

Answer (score 1):

In awk:

```
$ awk -F\| 'FNR==1{print FILENAME} $1=="THEAD"{print $2}' foo foo
foo
150001021
150001022
foo
150001021
150001022
```

On the first record of each file it prints out the filename and after that it prints the second field on records that start with `THEAD`. Replace `foo` with all required files.

Comment: Thank you very much this helped me to do the 1st doubth about doing it for multiple files.
But it still does not print the filename in the output. I'm only getting the ID's without the filename

Comment: remove the redirection operator `<` while supplying the file names.

Comment: The problem is that i need all files terminated in *.failed
Some day they can be 2, other day they can be 10 or even 50 different filles.
I guess my specification was not the most detailed... sorry for that.

What i did was:
`awk -F\| 'FNR==1{print FILENAME} $1=="THEAD"{print $2}' *.failed`

Comment: `awk -F\| 'FNR==1{print FILENAME} $1=="THEAD"{print $2}' *.failed`

Its not working as i hoped

Comment: I tried that `awk ... *` with three different awks and it worked with them all. If it don't work for you, try something else, like a shell `for` loop around the awk: `for i in *; do echo $i ; awk -F\| '$1=="THEAD"{print $2}' $i ; done`